# What's the simplest way to test MDM remote settings for iOS and mac as a developer?

Tags: ios, mobile, mdm

All I'm trying to do is get a key/value pair foo/bar from MDM.

This was straightforward and fairly simple for Android with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afwsamples.testdpc

The solution/technique should be

- vendor agnostic as much as possible (ie no intune SDK or anything app-specific that only works on one vendor)
- Not require DUNS number or credit card
- Work fine for a developer, can and probably would be a trial period MDM solution
- Something that works with NSUserDefaults

  ```
  UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")
  ```

Maybe it would use apple configurator and/or let the user upload a specific xml (similar to putting the info in AndroidManifest.xml for Android). Maybe apple configurator has been "locked down" recently; some instructions made it seem like it would "just work" - putting your phone next to the country code on the screen of your mac.

Tried

- Looking a long time in the documentation for apple configurator, apple for business, apple developer docs etc
- looking around some at some other MDM providers but didn't end up trying a trial YET, wanted some info from here first if possible or better yet a testDPC/AppleConfigurator type solution that wasn't vendorspecific if possible
- Trying to create and use an apple for business account to use with apple configurator after installing on mac and ios both, it appears to want a DUNS number and such, I'm just trying to do a developer test to verify, not do official red tape, iOS apple configurator wants a Device Enrollment Manager account; surely there's a way to test this as an app developer providing an app for orgs with multiple or even unknown MDM providers?

Comment: You don't need device enrolment. That is a feature where devices can ship from Apple directly to end users and the device will connect to your MDM during the initial setup; it is kind of a corporate version of activation lock; the device is locked to an organisation. You can use apple configuration to "supervise" a device and install some management payloads but this won't help you either. I don't believe that there is any way to put the payload  [without an MDM](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672782).

Comment: Short of having an MDM managed device, I think you just need to simulate the payload in your code and trust that it will get there.  In theory it is independent of the specific MDM solution in use since the MDM provides an XML payload as part of the standard Apple MDM command. It is always the same code in ios that receives the MDM command and sets up the app config payload

Comment: [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/sc2279/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013823-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_8) is very old but states that to test the device must be managed by an MDM